# Accessing the request from java to dotnet

Tags: c#, java, .net, servlets

Is it possible to pass a request from java servlet and read that request in dot net and give response to that call and vice versa...........

Waiting for your valuable commands

Comment: See this thread it might be a help http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=160345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by passing stream on tcp port and your dot net app read that stream and pass back the response to your Java app.

Comment: is it possible in http ot https ports

Comment: Yes it is possible to create webservice in any of these languages and consume them in any language

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest Web Service bridging architecture for your need. Either you can develop Web services in Java or Dot Net and/or Both as per the need.